# Change deeply nested key value of an object if there's an array of key names

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object and an array of the same object keys:

```
var obj = {
 'fieldOne': {
    'fieldTwo': {
        'fieldThree': {
            'fieldFour': {
                'someNestedKey': 'test'
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
var keysArr = ['fieldOne', 'fieldTwo', 'fieldThree', 'fieldFour', 'someNestedKey'];
```

Is there a way to change the 'someNestedKey' value using the keys array ?

Simply accessing the 'someNestedKey' by indexes won't work, because keys array may have more or less keys in it.
I tried somehow using array length, but I can't seem to get it working.
I'm relatively new to programming, would much appreciate any help.

Comment: How do you know that the last index is the value to change ? What if the length is bigger ?

Comment: Weedoze, in my case, last index is always the value to change

Comment: Rajesh, yes, unfortunately, it can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the path and make a check if the following element exist. If not assign an object to the new property.

Return then the value of the property.

At the end assign the value.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var way = path.slice(),
        last = way.pop();

    way.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r[a] = r[a] || {};
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

var obj = { fieldOne: { fieldTwo: { fieldThree: { fieldFour: { someNestedKey: 'test' } } } } },
    keysArr = ['fieldOne', 'fieldTwo', 'fieldThree', 'fieldFour', 'someNestedKey'];

setValue(obj, keysArr, 42);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I guess you can check for index, if its last and set value accordingly. `.slice` would cause extra iterations

Comment: it think it's better not to mutate the given data, beside the object.

Comment: I think I choose my words incorrectly. I meant, you are slicing and popping path array. Instead of these action, you can just check in `.reduce` if its the last iteration and if it is, set value to the key. I tried the same in my answer.

Comment: you could do it (obviously), but another check spoils the simplicity of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!

```
var obj = {
 'fieldOne': {
    'fieldTwo': {
    'fieldThree': {
        'fieldFour': {
            'someNestedKey': 'test'
        }
    }
    }
 }
}

var keysArr = ['fieldOne', 'fieldTwo', 'fieldThree', 'fieldFour', 'value'];

var obj1 = obj;
for (var i = 0; i < keysArr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (obj1[keysArr[i]]) {
        obj1 = obj1[keysArr[i]];
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

obj1[Object.keys(obj1)[0]] = keysArr[keysArr.length - 1];
```

After executing this code, 'someNestedKey' will be set to 'value'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
var obj = {
 'fieldOne': {
    'fieldTwo': {
        'fieldThree': {
            'fieldFour': {
                'someNestedKey': 'test'
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
var keysArr = ['fieldOne', 'fieldTwo', 'fieldThree', 'fieldFour', 'someNestedKey'];

var setThis = function(obj, keysArr, valueToSet){

var ref=obj ;
keysArr.forEach(function(key, index){
                    if(index==keysArr.length-1)
                      ref[key] = valueToSet ;
                    else
                     ref = ref[key] ;
              });
  alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
};  

setThis(obj, keysArr, "test123");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `eval` as well but do refer [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) before using.

#### Logic:

- If the object is properly constructed where the path is already initialised, you can create a string that would directly set value. This way you can skip looping.
- As a fallback, if there is a case where any of the values inside is not initialised, you can loop over path and set it manually.

```js
function updateValue(obj, path, value) {
  try {
    eval("obj[\"" + path.join("\"][\"") + "\"]=" + value)
    console.log("Used Eval")
  } catch (err) {
    path.reduce(function(p, c, i, a) {
      p[c] = (i === a.length - 1) ? value : p[c] || {};
      return p[c];
    }, obj);

    console.log("Used Loop")
  }
}

var obj = {
  'fieldOne': {
    'fieldTwo': {
      'fieldThree': {
        'fieldFour': {
          'someNestedKey': 'test'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
var keysArr = ['fieldOne', 'fieldTwo', 'fieldThree', 'fieldFour', 'someNestedKey']
var keysArr1 = ['fieldOne', 'fieldTwo', 'fieldThree', 'fieldFive', 'someNestedKey']

updateValue(obj, keysArr, 10);
console.log(obj)

updateValue(obj, keysArr1, 10);
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Please, if there is anything wrong with answer, do comment with your vote.