# How to set value to a property in a Javascript object, which is identified by an array of keys

Tags: javascript

If there is a Javascript object with multiple levels, as in:

```
   myObject = {
         a: 12,
        obj11: {
                obj111: 'John',
                b:13,
                obj1111: { a:15,
                           b: 35 }
        obj21: { 
                a:15,
                b:16 }
         }
```

I want to write a function to which is passed the object, an array of keys and the value to be assigned to the matched property.

```
 function myFunc (myObj,myArr, newValue) {
   ...
  }
  myFunc(myObject, ['obj11', 'obj1111'], {z:12});
  console.log(myObject.obj11.obj1111);
```

Should display {z:12}. 
Assume that the keys in the array are always correct.

Comment: You can loop over `myArr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` method to find nested object and if its found then you can use `Object.assign()` to add new property.

```js
var myObject = {"a":12,"obj11":{"obj111":"John","b":13,"obj1111":{"a":15,"b":35},"obj21":{"a":15,"b":16}}}

function myFunc (myObj, myArr, newValue) {
  myArr.reduce(function(r, e, i, arr) {
    if(!arr[i+1] && typeof r[e] == 'object') Object.assign(r[e], newValue);
    return r[e] || {}
  }, myObj)
}

myFunc(myObject, ['obj11', 'obj1111'], {z:12});
console.log(myObject)
```

**Update** If you just want to change value of nested property then you can use something like this.

```js
var myObject = {"a":12,"obj11":{"obj111":"John","b":13,"obj1111":{"a":15,"b":35},"obj21":{"a":15,"b":16}}}

function myFunc (myObj, myArr, newValue) {
  myArr.reduce(function(r, e, i, arr) {
    if(!arr[i+1] && r[e]) r[e] = newValue
    return r[e] || {}
  }, myObj)
}

myFunc(myObject, ['obj11', 'obj1111'], {z:12});
console.log(myObject)
```

Comment: I got the hang of it. But it will not work if I pass a scalar new value, as in myFunc(myObject, ['obj11', 'obj1111'], 25); which should assign 25 to obj11.obj1111

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunc(myObj,myArr,newValue){
  var temp=myObj;
  for(var I=0;I<myArr.length;I++){
    temp=temp[myArr[I]];
  }
  temp=newValue;
};
```

**Update**: This is a classic example of how you can access properties from an object in JavaScript.
You may, for simplicity, consider object as an array of properties. Now try and access the required property as if it is the index of the array.
If u have a nested object, consider it as a nested array.

Eg: console.log(myObj['obj11']['obj1111']);

The above code will display { a:15, b: 35 }, **before** running the myFunc() and will display {z:12} **after** running it.

Comment: Please add text to this answer to explain it a little