# Reconstruct a method from an array of strings and execute it

Tags: javascript

i have arrays like this: `['req','changepage']` or like this: `['dashboard','draw','ovreview']`

the result i need is:

```
mainObject.req.changepage()
```

and

```
mainObject.dashboard.draw.overview()
```

I know that i can do:

```
mainObject.[array[0]].[array[1]]()
```

but the length of the array may vary...
how to do that programatically?

Comment: Just use a loop?

Comment: Here's a solution that uses recursion: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jtk9L0ro/

Answer (score 2):

You can trivially [access a property using `reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46994085/1048572):

```
array.reduce((o, p) => o[p], mainObject)
```

but to make a method call on the right context object, you need to spare the last property access:

```
const methodname = array.pop();
array.reduce((o, p) => o[p], mainObject)[methodname]();
```

Alternatively, use `slice` if you don't want to mutate the array.

Comment: @MaheerAli Otherwise [the `this` keyword in the method doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572)

Comment: no need to pop in advance, the result is a function and the parentheses is the needed call. savind the last key is necessary for assigning a value to it.

Comment: @NinaScholz It's also necessary for calling the method as a method, with the object as the context. Otherwise, `reduce` returns a plain function that would be called with an `undefined` thisArg.

Answer (score 1):

Besides, `Array.reduce`, you could just use a loop.

```
let path = ['first', 'second', 'method'];

let target = {
  first: {
    second: {
      value: 'success',
      method: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg + this.value);
      }
}}};

let result = target;
for (let key of path.slice(0, -1)) {
    result = result[key];
}
result[path.slice(-1)]('result: ') // prints 'result: success'
```

As Bergi alludes to in their answer, the `Array.slice` calls (or a use of `Array.pop`) are needed if the function being called might ever reference `this`. In my example above, if you just use `let key of path`, then call `result('result: ')`, the output will be `result: undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

`.reduce` is useful for that:

```
  array.reduce((acc, key) => acc[key], mainObject)();
```

Or written using a plain `for` loop:

```
  let acc = mainObject;

  for(const key of array)
     acc = acc[key];

  acc();
```